Control visibility of bowings in lilypond
I made my own edition of a piece and I would like to generate 2 PDFs from it, one including my \upbow and \downbow markings, and one with no bowing indications. I have read this section:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/visibility-of-objects
But it doesn't describe how to figure out the name of the thing to turn off the stencil for. Their example says:
    \override Score.BarLine.stencil = ##f

What I can't figure out is what goes in place of "Score.Barline" to turn off upbows and downbows. It seems like this should be possible but I can't figure out how.

\override Score.BarLine.stencil = ##f

is to be read as: Under the Score context change the default stencil (i.e. what’s actually printed on the score) property of all BarLine grobs (graphical objects) to #f (false → nothing is printed).
Lilypond does by the way have a shorthand for than, which would be
\omit Score.BarLine

Now, the grob name of bow indicators is Script. Using that you could theoretically do the same. But this would affect also all other grobs of type Script, which includes pretty much eny type of ornament.
This effect you can see if you simply do
{
  \omit Script
  4-\upbow 4-^ 4-- 4-\fermata
}

But instead you can do something different. The default properties of Script type grobs are determined by the context property scriptDefinitions, which specifies a mapping between script names and the corresponding properties. So we can change this to specifically omit upbow and downbow:
\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    scriptDefinitions = #(cons*
                          `(upbow . ,(acons 'stencil #f (assoc-get 'upbow default-script-alist)))
                          `(downbow . ,(acons 'stencil #f (assoc-get 'downbow default-script-alist)))
                          default-script-alist)
  }
}

{
  4-\upbow 4-^ 4-- 4-\fermata
}

Here this is set for the whole Score context, but you can in fact set this at any context level, down to the Voice context. You can also add this to a \score { ... \layout { ... } } layout block to have this only affect certain scores and in \with { ... } blocks to have this affect only specific Staves or Voices in one Score. You can even use this with \set to change the behaviour:
{
  4-\upbow 4-^ 4-- 4-\fermata
  \set scriptDefinitions = #(cons*
                             `(upbow . ,(acons 'stencil #f (assoc-get 'upbow default-script-alist)))
                             `(downbow . ,(acons 'stencil #f (assoc-get 'downbow default-script-alist)))
                          default-script-alist)
  4-\upbow 4-^ 4-- 4-\fermata
}


Awesome, will try this out tonight!
